# Stuck at blinking cursor with Linux VMs

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

Host: Windows 10

VM: ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64

[image]

When I boot the VM it only shows the black screen with a blinking cursor.

I checked the BIOS, `VT-X` is enabled. Windows Hyper-V is also disabled.

VM Log didn't show `VT-X` error. What could be the problem?

```
00:00:06.225090 Features
00:00:06.225091   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:06.225097   FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                                   = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225100   VME - Virtual 8086 Mode Enhancements                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225103   DE - Debugging extensions                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225105   PSE - Page Size Extension                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225107   TSC - Time Stamp Counter                                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225109   MSR - Model Specific Registers                          = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225111   PAE - Physical Address Extension                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225113   MCE - Machine Check Exception                           = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225115   CX8 - CMPXCHG8B instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225117   APIC - APIC On-Chip                                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225120   SEP - SYSENTER and SYSEXIT Present                      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225122   MTRR - Memory Type Range Registers                      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225124   PGE - PTE Global Bit                                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225126   MCA - Machine Check Architecture                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225128   CMOV - Conditional Move instructions                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225130   PAT - Page Attribute Table                              = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225132   PSE-36 - 36-bit Page Size Extension                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225134   PSN - Processor Serial Number                           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225136   CLFSH - CLFLUSH instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225138   DS - Debug Store                                        = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225140   ACPI - Thermal Mon. & Soft. Clock Ctrl.                 = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225142   MMX - Intel MMX Technology                              = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225144   FXSR - FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions                  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225146   SSE - SSE support                                       = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225148   SSE2 - SSE2 support                                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225150   SS - Self Snoop                                         = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225153   HTT - Hyper-Threading Technology                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225155   TM - Therm. Monitor                                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225157   PBE - Pending Break Enabled                             = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225159   SSE3 - SSE3 support                                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225161   PCLMUL - PCLMULQDQ support (for AES-GCM)                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225163   DTES64 - DS Area 64-bit Layout                          = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225165   MONITOR - MONITOR/MWAIT instructions                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225167   CPL-DS - CPL Qualified Debug Store                      = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225169   VMX - Virtual Machine Extensions                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225170   SMX - Safer Mode Extensions                             = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225173   EST - Enhanced SpeedStep Technology                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225174   TM2 - Terminal Monitor 2                                = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225177   SSSE3 - Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225178   CNTX-ID - L1 Context ID                                 = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225180   SDBG - Silicon Debug interface                          = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225182   FMA - Fused Multiply Add extensions                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225184   CX16 - CMPXCHG16B instruction                           = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225186   TPRUPDATE - xTPR Update Control                         = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225188   PDCM - Perf/Debug Capability MSR                        = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225190   PCID - Process Context Identifiers                      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225192   DCA - Direct Cache Access                               = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225194   SSE4_1 - SSE4_1 support                                 = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225197   SSE4_2 - SSE4_2 support                                 = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225199   X2APIC - x2APIC support                                 = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225201   MOVBE - MOVBE instruction                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225203   POPCNT - POPCNT instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225205   TSCDEADL - Time Stamp Counter Deadline                  = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225207   AES - AES instructions                                  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225209   XSAVE - XSAVE instruction                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225211   OSXSAVE - OSXSAVE instruction                           = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225213   AVX - AVX support                                       = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225215   F16C - 16-bit floating point conversion instructions    = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225217   RDRAND - RDRAND instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225219   HVP - Hypervisor Present (we're a guest)                = 1 (0)
00:00:06.225221 Structured Extended Feature Flags Enumeration (leaf 7):
00:00:06.225222   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:06.225223   FSGSBASE - RDFSBASE/RDGSBASE/WRFSBASE/WRGSBASE instr.   = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225225   TSCADJUST - Supports MSR_IA32_TSC_ADJUST                = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225227   SGX - Supports Software Guard Extensions                = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225229   BMI1 - Advanced Bit Manipulation extension 1            = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225230   HLE - Hardware Lock Elision                             = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225232   AVX2 - Advanced Vector Extensions 2                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225234   FDP_EXCPTN_ONLY - FPU DP only updated on exceptions     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225236   SMEP - Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention             = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225238   BMI2 - Advanced Bit Manipulation extension 2            = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225240   ERMS - Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB instructions            = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225241   INVPCID - INVPCID instruction                           = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225243   RTM - Restricted Transactional Memory                   = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225245   PQM - Platform Quality of Service Monitoring            = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225247   DEPFPU_CS_DS - Deprecates FPU CS, FPU DS values if set  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225249   MPE - Intel Memory Protection Extensions                = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225250   PQE - Platform Quality of Service Enforcement           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225252   AVX512F - AVX512 Foundation instructions                = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225254   RDSEED - RDSEED instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225256   ADX - ADCX/ADOX instructions                            = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225258   SMAP - Supervisor Mode Access Prevention                = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225260   CLFLUSHOPT - CLFLUSHOPT (Cache Line Flush) instruction  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225262   INTEL_PT - Intel Processor Trace                        = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225264   AVX512PF - AVX512 Prefetch instructions                 = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225266   AVX512ER - AVX512 Exponential & Reciprocal instructions = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225267   AVX512CD - AVX512 Conflict Detection instructions       = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225269   SHA - Secure Hash Algorithm extensions                  = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225271   PREFETCHWT1 - PREFETCHWT1 instruction                   = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225273   UMIP - User mode insturction prevention                 = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225275   PKU - Protection Key for Usermode pages                 = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225276   OSPKE - CR4.PKU mirror                                  = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225279   MAWAU - Value used by BNDLDX & BNDSTX                   = 0x0 (0x0)
00:00:06.225281   RDPID - Read processor ID support                       = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225283   SGX_LC - Supports SGX Launch Configuration              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225285   MD_CLEAR - Supports MDS related buffer clearing         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225286   13 - Reserved                                           = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225289   IBRS_IBPB - IA32_SPEC_CTRL.IBRS and IA32_PRED_CMD.IBPB  = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225291   STIBP - Supports IA32_SPEC_CTRL.STIBP                   = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225292   FLUSH_CMD - Supports IA32_FLUSH_CMD                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225295   ARCHCAP - Supports IA32_ARCH_CAP                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225296   CORECAP - Supports IA32_CORE_CAP                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225298   SSBD - Supports IA32_SPEC_CTRL.SSBD                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225301 Processor Extended State Enumeration (leaf 0xd):
00:00:06.225302    XSAVE area cur/max size by XCR0, guest: 0x340/0x340
00:00:06.225304     XSAVE area cur/max size by XCR0, host: 0x440/0x440
00:00:06.225305                    Valid XCR0 bits, guest: 0x00000000`00000007 ( x87 SSE YMM_Hi128 )
00:00:06.225310                     Valid XCR0 bits, host: 0x00000000`0000001f ( x87 SSE YMM_Hi128 BNDREGS BNDCSR )
00:00:06.225315                     XSAVE features, guest:
00:00:06.225316                      XSAVE features, host: XSAVEOPT XSAVEC XGETBC1 XSAVES
00:00:06.225320       XSAVE area cur size XCR0|XSS, guest: 0x440
00:00:06.225321        XSAVE area cur size XCR0|XSS, host: 0x440
00:00:06.225322                Valid IA32_XSS bits, guest: 0x00000000`00000000
00:00:06.225324                 Valid IA32_XSS bits, host: 0x00000100`00000000 ( 40 )
00:00:06.225327   State #2, guest: off=0x0240, cb=0x0100 IA32_XSS-bit -- YMM_Hi128
00:00:06.225331   State #2, host:  off=0x0240, cb=0x0100 IA32_XSS-bit -- YMM_Hi128
00:00:06.225334   State #3, host:  off=0x03c0, cb=0x0040 IA32_XSS-bit -- BNDREGS
00:00:06.225337   State #4, host:  off=0x0400, cb=0x0040 IA32_XSS-bit -- BNDCSR
00:00:06.225341   State #8, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0080 XCR0-bit -- 8
00:00:06.225367          Unknown CPUID Leaves
00:00:06.225368      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
00:00:06.225414          Raw Hypervisor CPUID Leaves
00:00:06.225415      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
00:00:06.225416 Gst: 40000000/0000  40000001 4b4d564b 564b4d56 0000004d
00:00:06.225419 Hst:                00000834 00001068 00000064 00000000
00:00:06.225422 Gst: 40000001/0000  01000089 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225424 Hst:                00000834 00001068 00000064 00000000
00:00:06.225426          Raw Extended CPUID Leaves
00:00:06.225427      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
00:00:06.225428 Gst: 80000000/0000  80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225430 Hst:                80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225432 Gst: 80000001/0000  00000000 00000000 00000121 28100800
00:00:06.225434 Hst:                00000000 00000000 00000121 2c100800
00:00:06.225437 Gst: 80000002/0000  65746e49 2952286c 726f4320 4d542865
00:00:06.225439 Hst:                65746e49 2952286c 726f4320 4d542865
00:00:06.225443 Gst: 80000003/0000  37692029 3536382d 43205530 40205550
00:00:06.225445 Hst:                37692029 3536382d 43205530 40205550
00:00:06.225448 Gst: 80000004/0000  392e3120 7a484730 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225450 Hst:                392e3120 7a484730 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225452 Gst: 80000005/0000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225454 Hst:                00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225456 Gst: 80000006/0000  00000000 00000000 01006040 00000000
00:00:06.225457 Hst:                00000000 00000000 01006040 00000000
00:00:06.225459 Gst: 80000007/0000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
00:00:06.225461 Hst:                00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
00:00:06.225463 Gst: 80000008/0000  00003027 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225465 Hst:                00003027 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:06.225466 Ext Name:                        
00:00:06.225468 Ext Supports:                    0x80000000-0x80000008
00:00:06.225469 Family:                          0      Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:06.225471 Model:                           0      Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:06.225472 Stepping:                        0
00:00:06.225473 Brand ID:                        0x000
00:00:06.225474 Ext Features
00:00:06.225475   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:06.225476   FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                                   = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225484   VME - Virtual 8086 Mode Enhancements                    = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225486   DE - Debugging extensions                               = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225488   PSE - Page Size Extension                               = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225490   TSC - Time Stamp Counter                                = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225492   MSR - K86 Model Specific Registers                      = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225494   PAE - Physical Address Extension                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225496   MCE - Machine Check Exception                           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225498   CX8 - CMPXCHG8B instruction                             = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225500   APIC - APIC On-Chip                                     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225502   SEP - SYSCALL/SYSRET                                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225504   MTRR - Memory Type Range Registers                      = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225506   PGE - PTE Global Bit                                    = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225508   MCA - Machine Check Architecture                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225510   CMOV - Conditional Move instructions                    = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225512   PAT - Page Attribute Table                              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225514   PSE-36 - 36-bit Page Size Extension                     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225516   NX - No-Execute/Execute-Disable                         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225518   AXMMX - AMD Extensions to MMX instructions              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225520   MMX - Intel MMX Technology                              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225522   FXSR - FXSAVE and FXRSTOR Instructions                  = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225524   FFXSR - AMD fast FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225525   Page1GB - 1 GB large page                               = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225527   RDTSCP - RDTSCP instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225529   LM - AMD64 Long Mode                                    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225532   3DNOWEXT - AMD Extensions to 3DNow                      = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225534   3DNOW - AMD 3DNow                                       = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225536   LahfSahf - LAHF/SAHF support in 64-bit mode             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225538   CmpLegacy - Core multi-processing legacy mode           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225540   SVM - AMD Secure Virtual Machine extensions             = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225542   EXTAPIC - AMD Extended APIC registers                   = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225543   CR8L - AMD LOCK MOV CR0 means MOV CR8                   = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225545   ABM - AMD Advanced Bit Manipulation                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225547   SSE4A - SSE4A instructions                              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225549   MISALIGNSSE - AMD Misaligned SSE mode                   = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225551   3DNOWPRF - AMD PREFETCH and PREFETCHW instructions      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225553   OSVW - AMD OS Visible Workaround                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225555   IBS - Instruct Based Sampling                           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225557   XOP - Extended Operation support                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225559   SKINIT - SKINIT, STGI, and DEV support                  = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225560   WDT - AMD Watchdog Timer support                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225562   LWP - Lightweight Profiling support                     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225564   FMA4 - Four operand FMA instruction support             = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225566   NodeId - NodeId in MSR C001_100C                        = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225568   TBM - Trailing Bit Manipulation instructions            = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225570   TOPOEXT - Topology Extensions                           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225572   PRFEXTCORE - Performance Counter Extensions support     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225573   PRFEXTNB - NB Performance Counter Extensions support    = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225575   DATABPEXT - Data-access Breakpoint Extension            = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225577   PERFTSC - Performance Time Stamp Counter                = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225579   PCX_L2I - L2I/L3 Performance Counter Extensions         = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225580   MWAITX - MWAITX and MONITORX instructions               = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225583 Full Name:                       "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz"
00:00:06.225585 TLB 2/4M Instr/Uni:              res0     0 entries
00:00:06.225586 TLB 2/4M Data:                   res0     0 entries
00:00:06.225588 TLB 4K Instr/Uni:                res0     0 entries
00:00:06.225589 TLB 4K Data:                     res0     0 entries
00:00:06.225590 L1 Instr Cache Line Size:        0 bytes
00:00:06.225591 L1 Instr Cache Lines Per Tag:    0
00:00:06.225592 L1 Instr Cache Associativity:    res0  
00:00:06.225593 L1 Instr Cache Size:             0 KB
00:00:06.225594 L1 Data Cache Line Size:         0 bytes
00:00:06.225595 L1 Data Cache Lines Per Tag:     0
00:00:06.225595 L1 Data Cache Associativity:     res0  
00:00:06.225596 L1 Data Cache Size:              0 KB
00:00:06.225598 L2 TLB 2/4M Instr/Uni:           off       0 entries
00:00:06.225599 L2 TLB 2/4M Data:                off       0 entries
00:00:06.225600 L2 TLB 4K Instr/Uni:             off       0 entries
00:00:06.225601 L2 TLB 4K Data:                  off       0 entries
00:00:06.225602 L2 Cache Line Size:              0 bytes
00:00:06.225603 L2 Cache Lines Per Tag:          0
00:00:06.225604 L2 Cache Associativity:          off   
00:00:06.225604 L2 Cache Size:                   0 KB
00:00:06.225606   TS - Temperature Sensor                                 = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225608   FID - Frequency ID control                              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225610   VID - Voltage ID control                                = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225613   TscInvariant - Invariant Time Stamp Counter             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225615   CBP - Core Performance Boost                            = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225617   EffFreqRO - Read-only Effective Frequency Interface     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225618   ProcFdbkIf - Processor Feedback Interface               = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225620   ProcPwrRep - Core power reporting interface support     = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225623 Physical Address Width:          39 bits
00:00:06.225624 Virtual Address Width:           48 bits
00:00:06.225625 Guest Physical Address Width:    0 bits
00:00:06.225626 Physical Core Count:             1
00:00:06.225628 
00:00:06.225629 ******************** End of CPUID dump **********************
00:00:06.225630 *********************** VT-x features ***********************
00:00:06.225633 Nested hardware virtualization - VMX features
00:00:06.225634   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:06.225635   VMX - Virtual-Machine Extensions                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225636   InsOutInfo - INS/OUTS instruction info.                 = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225638   ExtIntExit - External interrupt exiting                 = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225639   NmiExit - NMI exiting                                   = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225640   VirtNmi - Virtual NMIs                                  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225641   PreemptTimer - VMX preemption timer                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225642   PostedInt - Posted interrupts                           = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225644   IntWindowExit - Interrupt-window exiting                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225645   TscOffsetting - TSC offsetting                          = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225646   HltExit - HLT exiting                                   = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225647   InvlpgExit - INVLPG exiting                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225648   MwaitExit - MWAIT exiting                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225649   RdpmcExit - RDPMC exiting                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225650   RdtscExit - RDTSC exiting                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225651   Cr3LoadExit - CR3-load exiting                          = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225653   Cr3StoreExit - CR3-store exiting                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225654   Cr8LoadExit  - CR8-load exiting                         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225655   Cr8StoreExit - CR8-store exiting                        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225656   UseTprShadow - Use TPR shadow                           = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225657   NmiWindowExit - NMI-window exiting                      = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225658   MovDRxExit - Mov-DR exiting                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225659   UncondIoExit - Unconditional I/O exiting                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225660   UseIoBitmaps - Use I/O bitmaps                          = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225661   MonitorTrapFlag - Monitor Trap Flag                     = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225662   UseMsrBitmaps - MSR bitmaps                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225663   MonitorExit - MONITOR exiting                           = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225664   PauseExit - PAUSE exiting                               = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225665   SecondaryExecCtl - Activate secondary controls          = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225666   VirtApic - Virtualize-APIC accesses                     = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225668   Ept - Extended Page Tables                              = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225669   DescTableExit - Descriptor-table exiting                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225670   Rdtscp - Enable RDTSCP                                  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225671   VirtX2ApicMode - Virtualize-x2APIC mode                 = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225672   Vpid - Enable VPID                                      = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225673   WbinvdExit - WBINVD exiting                             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225674   UnrestrictedGuest - Unrestricted guest                  = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225675   ApicRegVirt - APIC-register virtualization              = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225676   VirtIntDelivery - Virtual-interrupt delivery            = 0 (0)
00:00:06.225677   PauseLoopExit - PAUSE-loop exiting                      = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225678   RdrandExit - RDRAND exiting                             = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225679   Invpcid - Enable INVPCID                                = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225680   VmFuncs - Enable VM Functions                           = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225681   VmcsShadowing - VMCS shadowing                          = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225682   RdseedExiting - RDSEED exiting                          = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225683   PML - Page-Modification Log (PML)                       = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225684   EptVe - EPT violations can cause #VE                    = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225685   XsavesXRstors - Enable XSAVES/XRSTORS                   = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225686   EntryLoadDebugCtls - Load debug controls on VM-entry    = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225687   Ia32eModeGuest - IA-32e mode guest                      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225688   EntryLoadEferMsr - Load IA32_EFER MSR on VM-entry       = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225689   EntryLoadPatMsr - Load IA32_PAT MSR on VM-entry         = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225690   ExitSaveDebugCtls - Save debug controls on VM-exit      = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225691   HostAddrSpaceSize - Host address-space size             = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225693   ExitAckExtInt - Acknowledge interrupt on VM-exit        = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225694   ExitSavePatMsr - Save IA32_PAT MSR on VM-exit           = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225695   ExitLoadPatMsr - Load IA32_PAT MSR on VM-exit           = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225696   ExitSaveEferMsr - Save IA32_EFER MSR on VM-exit         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225697   ExitLoadEferMsr - Load IA32_EFER MSR on VM-exit         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225698   SavePreemptTimer - Save VMX-preemption timer            = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225699   ExitSaveEferLma - Save IA32_EFER.LMA on VM-exit         = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225700   IntelPt - Intel PT (Processor Trace) in VMX operation   = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225701   VmwriteAll - VMWRITE to any supported VMCS field        = 0 (1)
00:00:06.225702   EntryInjectSoftInt - Inject softint. with 0-len instr.  = 1 (1)
00:00:06.225703 
00:00:06.225704 ******************* End of VT-x features ********************
00:00:06.225739 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:06.225890 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=50000
00:00:06.225913 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:06.229037 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:06.229103 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:06.229117 AIOMgr:     C:\Users\arkce\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu18\ubuntu18.vdi
00:00:06.230010 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:06.230052 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:06.242976 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 6.1.2
00:00:06.243165 PCI: Setting up resources and interrupts
00:00:06.243749 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:06.250621 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:06.275984 VMMDev: Guest Log: CPUID EDX: 0x178bfbff
00:00:06.276352 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:06.276459 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:06.278509 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:06.278534 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:06.278669 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:06.278777 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:06.280635 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 0-P#0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 0x0000000007800000 sectors
00:00:06.284185 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:06.300113 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000daf0000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:06.732280 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:06.748615 GUI: 2D video acceleration is disabled
00:00:06.749263 GUI: HID LEDs sync is enabled
00:00:06.790441 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:08.774709 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:08.785518 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:08.786793 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0231
00:00:08.787771 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:08.788817 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0023
00:00:08.790930 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from CD-ROM...
```

Comment: In the dump there's a line "nested hardware virtualization," are you running Windows 10 in a VM also?

Comment: @essjae no host only one Windows 10 on physical machine.